# How to get the selected value of a Select control in a submitted form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I have a [form](https://ant.design/components/form/) with a [select](https://ant.design/components/select/) element placed (That I named 'type') in it, and I'm trying to get the values of each element after the form submit.

I have tried some approaches, but none was successful. My current code is below.

```
<Form
    partner={this.state.selectedPartner}
    onSaveClick={(record) => {
        const form = record.curre
        if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
            console.log('invalid')
            record.preventDefault();
            record.stopPropagation();
        } else {
            this.props.partner.add(
                record.target.elements.name.value, 
                record.target.elements.type.value, 
                record.target.elements.url.value, 
                record.target.elements.description.value
            )
        }                                            
    }}
/>
```

That results in *undefined* to the *type* element. What is the correct way to get that value?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the official [`Form.create` API](https://ant.design/components/form/#Form.create(options)) for it.

You **should use** `form.getFieldValue` or `form.getFieldsValue` without abusing the `event` object.

Here is a [minimal example](https://f4dlf.codesandbox.io/) of how it's done:

```js
function App({ form }) {
  const [selectValue, setSelectValue] = useState(undefined);
  const onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    form.validateFields((err, values) => {
      console.log('Received values of form: ', values);
      setSelectValue(values.select);
    });
  };
  return (
    <FlexBox>
      <Form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <Form.Item hasFeedback>
          {form.getFieldDecorator('select', {
            rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please select your country!' }]
          })(
            <Select
              placeholder="Please select a country"
              style={{ width: 300 }}
            >
              <Select.Option value="china">China</Select.Option>
              <Select.Option value="usa">U.S.A</Select.Option>
            </Select>
          )}
        </Form.Item>
        <Form.Item>
          <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
            Submit
          </Button>
        </Form.Item>
      </Form>
      <FlexBox>
        <h3>Selected value after Submit</h3>
        {selectValue}
      </FlexBox>
    </FlexBox>
  );
}

export default Form.create()(App);
```

[image: Edit AntdStart]